# Will 42.5 in vanity fit in 42 in space?

Tags: bathroom, vanity, measuring

Will this [vanity](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Rosedale-41-in-W-x-19-in-D-x-37-in-H-Single-Sink-Bath-Vanity-in-Taupe-Gray-with-White-Cultured-Marble-Top-RD42P2-TG/307838306#overlay) fit into a 42 1/8 in space between two walls? According to the [specification](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/d9/d9a300bf-63d8-415d-a1b4-c6045df51ddf.pdf), the base is 42 in and the counter top is 42.5 in and made of cultured marble. Although the top is larger than my available space, I'm wondering if the walls, which are made of dry wall, will compress enough to accommodate the top.

Here is the existing space:
[image]

And here's the one I want to buy:
[image]

Comment: Can you actually measure a top?  I've been caught out before by parts that are not exactly as the drawing.

Comment: From that angle it appears it has legs, but it actually has a recessed toe kick.

Comment: @D Duck Since it's online, I can't measure it myself.

Comment: Clearly if it will fit, the measurements are wrong. Since it's online and you can't measure it yourself, why not ask the vendor, or the manufacturer directly? How could anyone else guess?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suppose you could cut a channel into the drywall, if you actually have room to get the top lined up to shove in.

Unless you've arranged some fiendish hydrualic jack system that will more likely destroy the vanity top, the drywall won't compress under normal forces that won't damage your vanity top.

Depending what it's made of (not going to go read an ad for the thing to try and sort that out if you can't just tell us) you might be able to cut half an inch off the top, though. Well, you almost certainly can cut half an inch off the top, but some materials cut more easily and with less specialized tooling than others.

I'd suggest buying one that fits.

Comment: Top is made of cultured marble. Creating a groove is a better idea. The other issue that our drain pipe exits to the wall on the right, not in the back wall, and therefore we can't have drawers in the center or right. So this is the only vanity I could find that meets these requirements.

Comment: If you're going to put in a vanity with 1/8" clearance, you had better measure a bunch of places and make sure you actually have clearance at every part of the niche. Framers rarely build houses to great levels of precision, and you may find the vanity stuck half-way in due to inconsistencies in the walls.

Comment: Which implies that the **bottom** might not fit the 42" vanity base, with that much taper above the vanity top.

Comment: Whoops, I meant the opening is 42.5 at the bottom and 42 1/8 where top would be.

Comment: Depending on the walls, perhaps you could cut out the drywall on the sides up to the elevation of the top of counter, and replace with 1/4" drywall.  That would give you at least another 1/2" of space.  If you gave us a sketch or pics of the space that would go a lot further towards us giving you better ideas.

Comment: Recessing the top into the dry wall will only end badly because it will be almost impossible to seal it against water wicking up into the drywall.  Cut the top to fit or get a custom top.

Comment: Oh, now that you have a pic of the space, you're gonna need to (at least temporarily) remove the door trim no matter what you do.

Answer (score 9):

Cultured marble can be cut with a [diamond tile blade.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-7-in-Diamond-Blade-for-Wet-Tile-Saws-for-Ceramic-Tile-6-7001Q/203296581?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_014_FLOOR_TOOLS-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-2996251-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_TOOLS_FEED_G_NE_2023&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_014_FLOOR_TOOLS-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-2996251-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_TOOLS_FEED_G_NE_2023-71700000113756953-58700008517890442-92700077662636954&gclid=CjwKCAjwyY6pBhA9EiwAMzmfwZTFfWilyy7m60BEMmWUHJlcfCCBCzF0jwN6Q5GrvBwJ0bCRWmIr_hoCJBIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

I have done it a number of times and it is easier than ripping out or trying to cut grooves in the drywall.

If possible cut outside, wear eye, ear and breathing protection.

I use tape to mark the line I want to cut on. If you need 3/8 of an inch clearance, do yourself a favor and cut 1/4 off each end. Walls are rarely square and flat.

Comment: Sounds great. Until one looks at the lovely Roman ogee (or other) detail on the front and notices the nice square cut on the edge. However, this is one option to make it fit! (+1)

Comment: One would not see the ogee or other detail if the top were notched into the drywall either. Bottom line is something has to be sacrificed, because the laws of mathematics cannot be modified to allow something that is x to be inserted into a space that is x-y.